# Telethon Telegram API - Resolving invite link WITHOUT invoking ResolveUsernameRequest

Tags: telegram, telethon

I am currently building a software suite which takes in a few thousand telegram channels via their links (i.e. https://t.me/telegram_channel) and scrapes messages from them in order to do sentiment analysis. Everything works fine with the Telegram API and Telethon, however there is one problem I keep running into. In order to resolve the channel ID and user hash for each of these telegram channels, I need to run:

```
client.get_entity("https://t.me/telegram_channel")
```

However, this VERY quickly triggers `FloodWaitErrors` from the Telegram API, presumably because it thinks I may be attempting to resolve Telegram user's usernames in order to spam them.

That's not the case though. I am ONLY resolving public channels, not users or chats. I've searched for hours through the Telegram docs, and have not found a way to resolve a channel link WITHOUT invoking ResolveUsernameRequest and thus triggering a FloodWaitError. Is this possible to do without causing this rate limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because your own created `API_ID` and `API_HASH` are not official. It will run into `FloodWaitErrors` if you perform too many requests.

The easy way to solve this problem is by using **an Official API**.

#### Solution 1: Using [tdesktop](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop)'s API:

- The official Telegram Desktop app is using this API below:

  ```
  API_ID = 2040
  API_HASH = "b18441a1ff607e10a989891a5462e627"
  ```
- Use it with [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon):

  ```py
  client = TelegramClient("session", 2040, "b18441a1ff607e10a989891a5462e627")
  ```

However, there is a catch, as you can see in the [initConnection](https://core.telegram.org/method/initConnection) request of Telegram API, there are more than just `API_ID` and `API_HASH`, it also needs other parameters such as `device_model` or `lang_pack`. Telethon does provide you a way to set these parameters via `TelegramClient.__init__`, but it doesn't let you set the `lang_pack` parameters because [it's for official apps only](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/_client/telegrambaseclient.py#L192).

So that brings us to **Solution 2**.

#### Solution 2: Using a wrapper library of Telethon which provides official APIs.

- There is a library called [opentele](https://github.com/thedemons/opentele/) that provides a neat way to use official APIs, including the API of Desktop, Android, iOS, macOS,... that currently being used by official apps.
- First you need to install it from PyPi:

  > pip install opentele
- Then run the example code below:

  ```py
  from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
  from opentele.api import API
  import asyncio

  async def main():

      api = API.TelegramDesktop

      client = TelegramClient("telethon.session", api=api)
      await client.connect()

  asyncio.run(main())
  ```
- After that, you can use the `client` just like using it with Telethon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried OpenTele and still got hit with a FloodWaitError, even with a 2-5 second wait in between each resolve. I guess this simply isn't possible to do?

Comment: I've tested it with more than 1 million get_entity request in 26 hours straight. I use it to crawl messages from a supergroup, so it's definitely possible. Can you show me your code?

Comment: Edit: Sorry, i forgot to mention that you must use `client.QRLoginToNewClient()` to create a new session to ensure that it's registered as an official app on Telegram server.
After `client.connect()`, please do `client.PrintSessions()` to print the current sessions and check if it is official. You can refer to their docs to learn more, they're fully documented.

Comment: Official applications are prone to flood waits too.

Comment: @professor - this still doesn't work, here's my source - https://pastebin.com/1hXBf1wm

Comment: @professor If we can chat live and you can help me get it to work, I'll reward you for it. I've been searching through the docs for hours and still get limited even when using QRLogin and confirmed official via is_app_official() and the checkmark  from PrintSessions() by OpenTele

Comment: @Joshua sure, send me your telegram to my email, I'll text you
3pid3m1c.utqYKDiv9myvd93h@protonmail.com